# Visibility of textfield based on other value

Tags: javascript, jquery

HI I am new to JavaScript any help or suggestion will be really much appreciated.

I want my two *textfield* will be visible.

My code below is working for single only without semicolon but the variable sometimes with semicolon if multiple I am just wondering if its possible I will really appreciate advice.

```
var comp = "apple";

$( document ).ready(function() {
   var comp = "apple";
   $('#txt1').hide();
   $('#txt2').hide();
   $('#txt3').hide();
   if (comp == "apple"){
     $('#txt1').show();
   }

});
```

but if

```
 var comp = "apple;ice;grapes";
```

As *apple* and *grapes* is in the variable, *apple* and *grapes* should be visible.

Comment: You'll need to change the comparison from `==` to something that would match the substrings in your semicolon-separated string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==` returns *true* if the operands are equal. And obviously, `"apple;ice;grapes" != "apple"`.

You can use [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes):

> The [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) method determines whether one string may be found within another string, returning true or false as appropriate.

**Please Note:** You can pass multiple *id* as part of the selector to *hide()* them. But it is better to use *CSS* to set the *style* when possible.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  var comp = "apple;ice;grapes"; 
  //$('#txt1,#txt2,#txt3').hide();
  if (comp.includes("apple") && comp.includes("grapes")){
    $('#txt1, #txt2').show();
  }
});
```

```css
#txt1,#txt2,#txt3{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="txt1">apple</div>
<div id="txt2">grapes</div>
<div id="txt3">ice</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var comp = "apple;ice;grapes";
   var comp = comp.split(";"); //comp[0]='apple' comp[1]='ice' comp[2]='grapes';
        $('#txt1').hide();
        $('#txt2').hide();
        $('#txt3').hide();
   if (comp[0] == "apple"){
         $('#txt1').show();
   }
   if(comp[1] == "ice"){
         $('#txt2').show();
   } 

});   
</script>
```